# I only the first row of train_X and first value of train_y to train the SVM model...but the error I get is ''bad input shape ()''

Tags: python, svm

I have the following code and the error in Python: 
I want only the first row of `train_X` and first value of t`rain_y` to train the SVM model...
(I want to train the model on data sequentially by extracting the data from Iris data set one by one)

CODE:

```
np.random.seed(1)

iris = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv")
iris.drop("Id", axis=1, inplace = True)
iris = iris.values

train, test = train_test_split(iris, test_size=0.3) # our main data split 
into train and test

i=0
train_X1 = train_X[i:i+1,:]
train_y1 = train_y[i]     

model = svm.SVC() # select the svm algorithm

# we train the algorithm with training data and training output
model.fit(train_X1, train_y1)

# we pass the testing data to the stored algorithm to predict the outcome
prediction = model.predict(test_X)
print('The test accuracy of the SVM is :', 
metrics.accuracy_score(prediction,test_y)) 
# we check the accuracy of the algorithm
```

ERROR:

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()
>
> 8 # we train the algorithm with training data and training output
>   ----> 9 model.fit(train_X1, train_y1)
>
> ```
>  147         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
> ```
>
> --> 149         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr') 150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
>
> ```
>  545                         dtype=None) 546     else:
> ```
>
> --> 547         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True) 548         _assert_all_finite(y) 549     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
>
> ```
>  581         return np.ravel(y)
> ```
>
> --> 583     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
>            ValueError: bad input shape ()

Comment: You can't train a model with only one data point, i.e. a single row. I assume the SVM model is checking that you have at least two.

Comment: the model is not working for  more than 1 saples either e.g if I use                                                                                                                      i=50
train_X1 = train_X[i:i+1,:]
train_y1 = train_y[i]                                                                                                             I want to train the SVM model sequentially by extracting data samples from the Iris data set one by one. I dont think there is any logical mistake. The error is in the coding. I am new to python.